# Mocking a yaml file in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a yaml file, that has some config information and I use it in a module that I want to test. But when I test it I want to mock it so it only has simplified and static data, so it's easy to test and if the config is changed I don't have to edit the tests. Here is what I tried so far:

```
// config/index.js

const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'stuff.yaml');

module.exports =
{
    getStuff()
    {
        return yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));
    },
    setStuff(stuff)
    {
        fs.writeFile(filePath, yaml.safeDump(stuff), err => console.log);
    }
}

// test/config.test.js

const config = require("../config")

test('getStuff', () => {
    jest.mock('../config/stuff.yaml')
    expect(config.getStuff()).toEqual({/*..*/});
});
```

My file structure being:

```
project-root/
├── config/
│   ├── __mocks__/
|       └── stuff.yaml     (the mock file)
│   ├── stuff.yaml     (the real file)
│   └── index.js
└── test/
    └── config.test.js
```

But the test still return the data from the real file. Summarizing, I want to mock a text file in the file system, so that any module reads it instead of the real one.

Note: I don't really care if the mock version is on the disk or I just have it as a string in memory. Having it in memory would even be beneficial in the sense of the tests being faster.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just mock it yourself. I realize that's not what you want, so I'm just commenting, but manually mocking in JavaScript is very easy and straightforward... even more so when it is just static data.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably update your Jest configuration and leverage `moduleNameMapper` to handle this.

```
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "config/stuff.yaml": "<rootDir>/config/__mocks__/stuff.yaml"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setMock - https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestsetmockmodulename-moduleexports

`jest.setMock('config/__mocks__/stuff.yaml', require('config/stuff.yaml');`